# Rails 4 WYSIWYG Bootsy image upload option not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, wysiwyg

Hi i am using Bootsy and it is work fine, unfortunatly image upload option is not working I have already installed CarrierWave which is also working fine.

**My form**

```
<%= f.bootsy_area(:description) %>
```

**My Model**

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

      belongs_to :user
      include Bootsy::Container

      require 'carrierwave/orm/activerecord'
      mount_uploader :attachment, AttachmentUploader

      extend FriendlyId

      friendly_id :title, use: :slugged


      validates :title, :presence => true
      validates :slug, :presence => true
      validates :user_id, :presence => true

      def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
        new_record? || !self.slug.present? && self.title.present?
      end

    end
```

**My controller**

```
def pages_params
    params.require(:page).permit(:title, :description, :status, :slug, :user_id, :password, :attachment, :bootsy_image_gallery_id)
end

def create
  @page = Page.new(pages_params)

  if @page.save
    redirect_to(:action => "index")
  else
    render("new")
  end
end
```

any any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have found the answer yet, here is what I found with the similar problem and its solution.

[After upload images, how to insert the image?](https://github.com/volmer/bootsy/issues/105)